# Segmentation fault when passing pointer to function

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault when I call my getField(char *line, int field) function in my while loop and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to pass a line to the function and a column number so that I can grab specific columns from each line in a csv file and print them to the screen. Thanks for input.

```
void getField(char *line, int field);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if(argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments \"%s\".\n", argv[0]);
  }

  if(atoi(argv[1]) < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "First argument must be >= 1 \"%s\".\n", argv[1]);
  }
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if(fp == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", argv[0]);
  char buf[80];
  while(fgets(buf, 80, fp) != NULL) {
    getField(buf, atoi(argv[1]);  // seg fault is happening here
  }

  return 0;
}

void getField(char *line, int field) {
  printf("here2");
  //char *ln = line;
  int column = field - 1;
  int idx = 0;
  while(column) {
    //printf("here");
    if(line[idx] == ',') field--;
    idx++;
  }

  for(int j = idx; ; ++j) {
    if(line[j] == ',') break;
    printf("%s", line[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("%d", idx);
}
```

Comment: Exactly which line is the segfault happening in?

Comment: Can you run gdb and post the backtrace for the seg fault?

Comment: In your 1st test you should stop the program, there is not point in continuing if there are not enough arguments.

Comment: @merlin2011 it's happening before the call to getField(). It's not even calling it.

Comment: In the while loop `while(column) ...` you are looping till `column` does not become zero. But you are never updating `column`.

Comment: 1) if `fp == NULL` then you must return and you don't must pass this pointer to function. 2) `printf("%s", line[j]);` -> `printf("%s", &line[j]);`

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger. This kind of little programs can be debugged in no time if you know how to use the basics of a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious error is that you have an infinite loop here, and you will eventually access illegal memory.

```
while(column) {
     //printf("here");
    if(line[idx] == ',') field--;
    idx++;
}
```

You are not modifying `column` at all, so your loop cannot possibly end. 
`column` will not update itself when you update `field`, so you will have to update it if you want it to update.

```
while(column) {
     //printf("here");
    if(line[idx] == ',') field--;
    idx++;
    column = field - 1;
}
```

**Note on debugging segfaults using `printf`.**

The function `printf` prints to `stdout` and `stdout` likes to buffer output. This means that sometimes if you try to find a segfault by moving a print statement down your code until it fails to print, you will misunderstand where the segfault it happening. In particular, a `printf` line that appears before the line that actually contains the segfault may not print even if you might expect it to.

If you want to use this strategy (instead of `gdb`), you can force it to print by using `fflush(stdout);` immediately after your debugging `printf`.

Comment: Yeah, I used field-- instead of column-- by mistake. Why isn't the first printf("here") function being called in the first line of my getField function?

Comment: Because `printf` prints to `stdout` and `stdout` likes to buffer output. You can force it to print by using `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Interesting.. I did not know that. Thank you very much for the help. I was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(column) {
        //printf("here");
        if(line[idx] == ',') column--;  // Changed field-- to column--
                idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In following line:

```
printf("%s", line[j]);
```

you are using the `%s` format specifier but you are passing a `char` as argument.

You probably want this (`%c` format specifier fot printing a `char`):

```
printf("%c", line[j]);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the problems. I appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing out of bounds of the array in the function `getField` because the `while` loop never exits. This invokes undefined behaviour and most likely program crash due to segfault which is what is happening in your case. I suggest the following changes to your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getField(char *line, int field);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if(argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too few arguments \"%s\".\n", argv[0]);
    return 1; // end the program
  }

  if(atoi(argv[1]) < 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "First argument must be >= 1 \"%s\".\n", argv[1]);
    return 1; // end the program
  }

  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", argv[0]);
    return 1; // end the program
  }

  char buf[80];
  while(fgets(buf, 80, fp) != NULL) {
    getField(buf, atoi(argv[1]));  // seg fault is happening here
  }

  return 0;
}

void getField(char *line, int field) {
  int len = strlen(line);
  char temp[len + 1];
  strcpy(temp, line);

  int count = 0;
  char ch = ',';
  char *p = temp;
  char *q = NULL;
  while(count < field - 1) {
    q = strchr(p, ch);
    if(q == NULL) {
      printf("error in the value of field\n");
      return;
    }
    count++;
    p = q + 1;
  }
  q = strchr(p, ch);
  if(q != NULL)
    *q = '\0';
  else 
    temp[len-1] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", p);
}
```